# O que são Macros e como utilizá-las?

Tags: c, c++, macro

Até o momento durante meu curso de programação em C, o único contato que tive com macros vieram de bibliotecas padrão e sem saber muito bem o que ocorria ao chamar estas macros.
Gostaria de saber o que são exatamente macros, como criar uma em C/C++ e a diferença entre macro, função e constante. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros ou Microinstruções é um recurso de pré compilação (preprocessamento) que permite criar estruturas que serão substituídas antes do código ser compilado.

Uma Macro pode vir a representar uma simples string que irá repetir em quantidade no código, como também pode representar um bloco de código relativamente complexo ou dentro de um domínio de aplicação, porém que seja repetido diversas vezes no código, e a chamada de função ficaria deselegante.

Em caso de Macros para códigos, podem vir a ser usado para se criar dialetos da linguagem com o C ou C++ para domínio específico, assim pode se adotar nomes de constantes matemáticas, blocos de código nomeados que ficam melhor organizados e legíveis para especialistas do domínio em uso.

Macros também pode vir a ser usado para identificar constantes que serão usadas para definir arquiteturas, reestruturando o código criando uma compilação condicional.

Os arquivos de código são interpretados por pré compilador que substitui tais macros pelas suas representações, gerando um novo arquivo de código que será compilado.

Quando uma Macro chama outras macros é importante tomar certas precauções como sugeridas no artigo [C-Preprocessor Tricks, Tips and Idioms](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms).

Outras informações sobre [PreProcessamento em C (em inglês)](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/cpreprocessor.html)

Comment: Acho que vale ressaltar que a utilização de macros em C++ normalmente não é bem vista pois macros não oferecem segurança de tipos, não respeitam escopo (estou olhando para vocês min e max do windows.h rs) e podem dificultar a compreensão do funcionamento de um trecho de código quando fazem algo que não poderia ser feito com outras funcionalidades da linguagem. Citando sua resposta, em C++ no geral é preferível que se use variáveis constantes para constantes matemáticas e funções (possivelmente templates) para blocos de código nomeados, evitando assim os problemas mencionados.

Comment: Exato @TiagoGomes, obrigado por complementar, inclusive no último link que enviei fala sobre isso no final, mas está em inglês.